node.js and express Session are not working
Session are not working. I saved the session token in post login request and I did not received token in dashboard request
What am I doing wrong?
const express = require('express');
const axios = require("axios");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cors = require('cors');
//var store  = new express.session.MemoryStore;
const app = express();
//app.use(express.cookieParser());
const corsOption = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:3001']
}
app.use(cors(corsOption));
app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
require('dotenv').config()
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    }));
app.post("/login",(req,res,next) => {
     axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_API+'?grant_type=password&client_id='+process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET
    +'&username='+process.env.REACT_APP_USERNAME+'&password='+process.env.REACT_APP_PASSWORD).then((response) => {
        req.session.token = response.data.access_token;
        axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+'uservalidation?UserEmailID='+req.body.email+'&Password='+req.body.password, 
          { 'headers': { 'Authorization': "Bearer "+  req.session.token } })
          .then((response) => {
              if(response.data.responsecode == "200"){  
                req.session.email = req.body.email;
                console.log(req.session)
                 res.json(response.data);
              } else {
                 res.json({'error':"Invalid Email/Password"});
              }
              next();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
    });
});
app.get("/dashboard",(req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req.session);
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+"oemdashboard/?UserEmailID="+req.session.email ,
        { 'headers': { 'Authorization': "Bearer "+req.session.token } })
        .then((response) => {
            res.json(response.data);
            next();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
            // Redirect to the login page
            res.json({'error':"Failed to fetch data"});
            }
        });
});
app.listen(5000,()=>{console.log("Server Started on Port 5000")})


I think you are missing saving the session in first place after login.
Save the session using req.session.save();

Why didn't you use storage(redis,mongoDB) for session data?
It is good practice to use session storage.
Though you can initialize and use sessions in Express without specifying a session store but not without cookie.
Try this in place of your code.
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat', 
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,              //set to "true" if using HTTPS
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 1 day in milliseconds
  }
}));

The core functionality of sessions depends on cookies to store the session ID on the client side, which is then used to identify the session on the server side.But session data is stored in the server itself.So it is not good practice to initialize session without cookies.
